# Cast object using type stored in a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, enums, casting, swift5

**How can I cast an object using a type (stored in a parameter)?**

**Example:**

Let's assume I have a simple `enum` like so:

```
enum SettingsAction {
    case contactUs

    var cellType: UITableViewCell.Type {
        return TitleSettingsTableViewCell.self
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to create an object with `cellType`, like so:

```
let settingsAction = SettingsAction.contactUs
let cellType = settingsAction.cellType
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(cellType)", for: indexPath) as! cellType
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find type 'cellType' in scope
```

Seems like it's impossible to use a parameter to cast, resulting in some weird pre-complier error.

**Is there a right way to achieve what I'm trying?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this -

```swift
enum SettingsAction {
    case contactUs

    func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, in tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch self {
        case .contactUs:
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TitleSettingsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TitleSettingsTableViewCell
        }
    }
        
}
```

**Update**
Swift won't allow you to work with `Type` information stored in a variable that's only available at runtime. This information is needed at compile time for the type inference.
You have to give up flexibility in one way or another.
Here's another attempt at solving the same problem - far from ideal - it does work as needed for this use case.

```swift
class UserInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var userProperty: Bool = false
}
class ContactUsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var contactProperty: Bool = false
}
class LegalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var legalProperty: Bool = false
}

class SettingsCellCreator<T: UITableViewCell> {
    func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, in tableView: UITableView) -> T {
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(T.self)", for: indexPath) as! T
    }
}

private let userInfoCellCreator = SettingsCellCreator<UserInfoTableViewCell>()
private let contactUsCellCreator = SettingsCellCreator<ContactUsTableViewCell>()
private let legalCellCreator = SettingsCellCreator<LegalTableViewCell>()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    enum CellType {
        case userInfo
        case contactUs
        case legal
    }
    
    private var rows: [CellType] = [
        .userInfo,
        .contactUs,
        .contactUs,
        .legal,
        .legal
    ]
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        rows.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch rows[indexPath.row] {
        case .userInfo:
            let cell = userInfoCellCreator.cellForRow(at: indexPath, in: tableView)
            cell.userProperty = true
            return cell
            
        case .contactUs:
            let cell = contactUsCellCreator.cellForRow(at: indexPath, in: tableView)
            cell.contactProperty = true
            return cell
            
        case .legal:
            let cell = legalCellCreator.cellForRow(at: indexPath, in: tableView)
            cell.legalProperty = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That’s my workaround tbh, searching for a more of a “automated solution ”. Thank tho!

Comment: See the update to my answer. This is more close to a real world use case where you need to work with multiple types of cells in one tableView. Each row can contain it's own data model using enum case associated values.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift the right side of downcasting `as` and type checking `is` operators must be given in place of use of those operators.

So, it's impossible to cast or type check an object using a meta type stored or computed.